# Random image in GridView

Tags: android

I was wonder there is anyway to random image in GridView

The code bellow is working well for me but it's doesn't random image in GridView when start activity.

What should I modify code bellow to make it random?

Layout:

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/fruit_gridview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Image Adapter:

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.apricot,
        R.drawable.banana, R.drawable.bell,
        R.drawable.blueberries, R.drawable.broccoli,
        R.drawable.carrot, R.drawable.celery,
        R.drawable.cherry, R.drawable.chili,
        R.drawable.coconut, R.drawable.dragon_fruit,
        R.drawable.durian, R.drawable.eggplant,
        R.drawable.erdnuss, R.drawable.grape,
        R.drawable.guava, R.drawable.kiwi,
        R.drawable.lettuce, R.drawable.lychee,
        R.drawable.mango, R.drawable.mangosteen,
        R.drawable.passion, R.drawable.mengkudu,
        R.drawable.mushroom, R.drawable.onion,
        R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.pear,
        R.drawable.pineapple, R.drawable.pomegranate,
        R.drawable.potato, R.drawable.pumpkin,
        R.drawable.radish, R.drawable.strawberry,
        R.drawable.tomato, R.drawable.watermelon
};
```

GridView Activity:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.fruit_gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter_Fruit_24(this));

    final ImageAdapter_Fruit_24 imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter_Fruit_24(this);
```

Thanks you!

Comment: isn't your problem solved?

Comment: No, still can't solve.

Comment: okay. Is it possible to replace `Integer[]` with `ArrayList`? Both have same functionality. I have other solution if you want to do. By using array, you can get any value by its `get(position)` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code before displaying or giving to Adapter.

```
// Fisher–Yates shuffle
static void shuffleArray(Integer[] intArr) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = intArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        // Simple swap
        int temp = intArr[index];
        intArr[index] = intArr[i];
        intArr[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

You can also convert it to `ArraryList<Integer>` or `List`. `Collections` has its own method `shuffle`.

```
List list = Arrays.asList( solutionArray );
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

**Edit**

Convert `Integer[]` to `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 1 ; i < intArr.length ; i++)
{
    arrList.add(intArr[i]);
}
Collections.shuffle(arrList);
```

To use `arrList`, use `arrList.get(position)` method.

**Example**

I have all the Integer array like yours. I have implemented on my way.

```
Log.d("Home","Before Shuffle");
    for(int i=0;i< mThumbIds.length;i++){
        Log.i("Home",""+mThumbIds[i]);
}
```

output will be like following. (Don't compare with your output. Resource ids may different)

> 06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837504
>   06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837505
>   06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837508
>   06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837507
>   06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837506
>   06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837509
>   06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837510
>   06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837511

Now, I converted this `Integer[]` to `ArrayList<Integer>`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i< mThumbIds.length;i++){
    list.add(mThumbIds[i]);
}
```

Now, Shuffle list and print.

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
for(int i=0;i< list.size();i++){
    Log.i("Home",""+list.get(i));
}
```

Output. (Every time you run your code, output will be different. So don't compare with previous one.)

> 06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837511
>   06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837504
>   06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837506
>   06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837508
>   06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837510
>   06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837505
>   06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837507
>   06-19 12:49:53.489: INFO/Home(2627): 2130837509

You can see the sequence of your list. Its different then before. To use in your code.

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.fruit_gridview);
//do shuffle of list. make sure you have write above code before this
Collections.shuffle(list);
ImageAdapter_Fruit_24 imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter_Fruit_24(this);
gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

In your `getView()`.

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    //here changes will be done
    imageView.setImageResource(list.get(position));
    return imageView;
}
```