# How to random gridview in android code

Tags: android

Is there anyway to customize to random image in GridView [from this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

I am working on it and it give a very good result, but the image in gridview was not randomly. Can anyone guide me some techniq to customize this?

Thank you!

Comment: What images are you displaying?  Where are they coming from? How are you creating the GridView and/or adapter?  Please show your code.

Comment: If you, for example, have your images in List, then Collections.shuffle(arrayList);

Comment: Hi Aleks, The image from R.drawable.1; R.drawable.2; R.drawable.3; .... R.drawable.n;

Comment: Dear Macialov, Thank you very much if you give me a clearly code than this.

Comment: look at my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183803/random-image-in-gridview/17183981#17183981

Comment: Dear Chintan, The like is not clear enough. I really don't know where to insert and what the part of code to use.

Comment: @user1731690 show us what you have so far (your code)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are doing something like this:

```
Integer[] images = {
            R.drawable.1, R.drawable.2,
            R.drawable.3, ... ,R.drawable.n
    };
```

now you have an array of references to your drawables.

```
List<Integer> imagesArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(images))
```

this would convert your array to ArrayList

```
Collections.shuffle(imagesArrayList);
```

from doc:

> Collections.shuffle : Randomly permutes the specified list using a
>   default source
>   of randomness.

Then in **getView** method (I assume you are using custom adapter like in [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/) example)

```
int[] tempArrayList = Ints.toArray(imagesArrayList);
imageView.setImageResource(tempArrayList[position]);
```

P.S. Haven't compiled it, so there might be errors